# Finding the unit normal to a cone.

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, surfaces

[image]

[image]

**MY METHOD:**

I thought I would use the conventional method for finding the unit normal vector by calculating the gradient of S. Where $S: x^2 +y^2 - z^2 = 0$.

$\hat n = \frac{\nabla S}{mag[\nabla S]}$

$\hat n = \frac{2x \hat i + 2y \hat j -2z \hat k}{\sqrt{(2x)^2 +(2y)^2 +(2z)^2   }}$

$\hat n = \frac{2x \hat i + 2y \hat j -2z \hat k}{\sqrt{(4x^2 +4y^2 +4z^2   }}$

$\hat n = \frac{2x \hat i + 2y \hat j -2z \hat k}{\sqrt{(4r^2 +4r^2}}$

giving $\hat n$ as:

$\hat n = \frac{x \hat i + y \hat j -z \hat k}{\sqrt{2}}$ which is not equivalent to the solution above.

Also does anyone know exactly what they did? I am having difficult to comprehend it. Why is are they calculating the cross product of the partials? Is it to do with multivariable chain rule - which is so can someone expand on this explanation by going more in depth?

**Addition Edit**

I saw this equation on the internet but am unsure why that is the case. Why are they multiplying again by the magnitude?

[image]

Any help is much appreciated!!

Comment: I suppose they use, as you, an unitary normal vector. Now, consider $dxdy$; it is the area element into the $xy$ plane, not the area element along the surface, so it need to be compensated, precisely with the true area: $\left|\dfrac{\partial\vec r}{\partial x}\times\dfrac{\partial\vec r}{\partial y}\right|$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works well too. Try better with $z-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=0$

$\vec n=(-z_x,-z_y,1)=\left(\dfrac{-x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}},\dfrac{-y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}},1\right)=(\cos\theta,\sin\theta,1)$

$d\mathbf S=\vec ndS=(-z_x,-z_y,1)dxdy=(-\cos\theta,-\sin\theta,1)rdrd\theta $

$=(-r\cos\theta,-r\sin\theta,r)drd\theta$

Comment: The partial derivative of z w.r.t. x is equal to: $\frac{2x}{\sqrt{x^2 +y^2}}$ So why does the 2 disappear in your case?

Comment: $1/2$ from the square root and $2$ from the square.